# Not able to perform transformations and extract JSON values from Flink DataStream and Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming

I am trying to read data from the Kafka topic and I was able to read it successfully. However, I want to extract data and return it as a `Tuple`. So for that, I am trying to perform `map` operation but it is not allowing me to perform by saying that `cannot resolve overloaded method 'map'`. Below is my code:

```
  package KafkaAsSource

import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer

import java.util.Properties

object ReadAndValidateJSON {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    //env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    val data:DataStream[String] = getDataFromKafkaTopic(properties,env)


    val mappedData: DataStream[jsonData] = data.map(v => v)
      .map {
        v =>
          val id = v["id"]
          val category = v["category"]
          val eventTime = v["eventTime"]
          jsonData(id,category,eventTime)
      }
    
    data.print()


    env.execute("ReadAndValidateJSON")
  }

  def getDataFromKafkaTopic(properties: Properties,env:StreamExecutionEnvironment): DataStream[String] = {

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("maddy1", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
    consumer.setStartFromEarliest()
    val src: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(consumer)
    return src
  }

}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink-version}</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
            <version>${flink-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-cassandra_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${flink-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Kafka Topic Data:

```
{
  "id":"7",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-27 20:52:58.708"
  
}
{
  "id":"9",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-27 20:52:58.727"
  
}
{
  "id":"10",
  "Category":"Flink",
  "eventTime":"2021-12-27 20:52:58.734"
  
}
```

Where am I exactly going wrong? Are the dependencies correct? My Flink version is 1.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```

Comment: In my case, I removed wrong `datastream`, `streamexecutionenvironment` imports and just used the import suggested by @David and it worked :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!